# why isn't Beautifulsoup accepting a unicode input?

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using requests to download a webpage and using BS4 to parse it. 
It works find for some links; however when sometimes it gives me the following error

> Expected a bytes object, not a unicode object

In the Beautiful soup documentation it says that unicode is fine:

> If you pass in a byte string, Beautiful Soup will assume the string is encoded as UTF-8. You can avoid this by passing in a Unicode string instead.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
link= "http://www.nytimes.com/2014/03/03/world/europe/ukraine.html?hpw&rref=world"
def get_article(link):
    p=requests.get(link).text
    print p
    soup=BeautifulSoup(p)
    paragraphs=soup.find_all('p',class_="story-body-text story-content")
    print paragraphs
    return paragraphs
def get_text(paragraphs):
    text=""
    for paragraph in paragraphs:
       text+=paragraph.text
    return text
print get_text(get_article(link))
```

The link given in the code raises the error; this link will not http://www.nytimes.com/2014/03/02/world/asia/afghan-broadcaster-says-us-soldiers-abused-him.html?ref=world

Traceback:

```
Message File Name       Line    Position       
Traceback                              
        C:\Users\Acer Customer\Desktop\Project\nytscraper.py    27             
    get_article C:\Users\Acer Customer\Desktop\Project\nytscraper.py    17             
    get C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py   55             
    request     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py   44             
    request     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py      383            
    send        C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py      506            
    resolve_redirects   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py      168            
    send        C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py      486            
    send        C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py      378            
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.nytimes.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /2014/03/03/world/europe/pressure-rising-as-obama-works-to-rein-in-russia.html?_r=0 (Caused by : [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)
```

Comment: I am not getting any error!

Comment: `paragraphs=soup.find_all('p',class_="story-body-text story-content") `does not retrieve anything even if the page has p with given class for given url. Thats wierd

Comment: even just `paragraphs=soup.find_all('p')` just sshows a single paragraph when there are multiple paragraphs on the page ...hmmm

Comment: @S.M.AlMamun it is working fine for you? No errors; and gives you the correct output?

Comment: yes, I don't get any!

Comment: @S.M.AlMamun does it print out the article?

Comment: you might have `lxml` module installed (bs4 may use it if it is available). `lxml` might produce the error. Try [`bs4.diagnose.diagnose(p)`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#diagnose)

Comment: Do you get any errors if you use `p = requests.get(link).content`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I tried .content. It gets rid of the error, but I only get the first paragraph of the article.

Comment: I get a really long error when using diagnose: http://pastebin.com/QTarn8nM  From my basic google search, i think this means that I am hitting the website too often, but why would it work on some websites and not others? Also the webpage downloads fine, it is the parsing that gets screwed up.

Comment: @JONPON: `.content` returns **all** content from the `link` (not just the first paragraph). It fixes your  *"Expected a bytes object, not a unicode object"* error. It doesn't fix **other** errors you might have such as *"Max retries exceeded with url: "* -- it is **not** parsing problem: it is raised **before** BeautifulSoup is called. It can't retrieve the url due to `ConnectionError`. It might be a temporary condition.

Comment: *"I get a really long error when using diagnose"* -- `ConnectionError` is unrelated to `diagnose.diagnose(content)` because the function hasn't been called yet.

Comment: *"I only get the first paragraph of the article"* -- `class_="story-body-text story-content"` matches only the exact value, try `L = soup.select("p.body-text.story-content")` instead

Comment: Yeah, sorry I think the error was just because of my internet connection. After running diagnose it told me to try html.parser. I will take a look at it later. .content has the same problem. The script runs much slower on websites that do not work.

Comment: Actually the select  does not work on links where find_all works. Also when i said "content" in the previous comment I meant "select" However, when I change to select to soup.select("p.story-body-text.story-content") it does work. (but still gives me errors in the place find_all would give me errors)